# html input value is garbled when I input non-ANSI characters

Tags: javascript, html

HTML5 email input tag value is garbled when I input Portuguese characters to it.

```js
 function test() {
  console.log(document.querySelector("input[type=email]").value)
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="email" placeholder="input your email here">
 <button onclick="javascript:test();">Confirm</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Test input is `xpto@sdjdsk.çom` and it prints `xpto@sdjdsk.xn--om-3ia` in console.

However, if I change input tag like this:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="input your email here" value="xpto@sdjdsk.çom">
```

it prints `xpto@sdjdsk.çom`.

What is the reason and how can I solve it? (Workaround is OK.)

Comment: A note for those coming along, this **isn't** a limitation of the console, you get the same issue dumping back to the DOM: https://jsfiddle.net/yq26s3nm/

Comment: @JonP I found something interesting. If you add any quotation mark in the beginning, you will get the correct result with the quotation mark. e.g. `"xpto@sdjdsk.çom` will dump `"xpto@sdjdsk.çom` correctly.

Comment: More interesting still, change the input type to "text" and it works : https://jsfiddle.net/yq26s3nm/1/ . It *may* be an issue with validating ".çom" as a Top Level Domain, but I'm guessing.

Comment: @JonP I think this is Chrome's fault. Works correctly in Firefox.
Although it's not valid email in Firefox, it is valid in Google Chrome and get the value wrongly.

Comment: Also note as is stands "sdjdsk.çom" works. As soon as you add @ preceded by another character it fails.

Comment: @JonP Someone told me that it's punycoding feature that Chrome supports. But firefox does not support it. If you're interested, please refer to my answer in this question.

Comment: Good work on finding the dupe.... marked to close as dupe